# Spring bean not being picked up?

Tags: java, spring

I have a java spring project with the below service:

```
@Slf4j
public class DialogFlowService {

    private String projectId;
    private String sessionId;
    private String languageCode;

    public DialogFlowService(DialogFlowConfig dialogFlowConfig) {
        log.info("aaa" + dialogFlowConfig.languageCode);
        this.projectId = dialogFlowConfig.projectId;
        this.sessionId = dialogFlowConfig.sessionId;
        this.languageCode = dialogFlowConfig.languageCode;
    }
}
```

The constructor takes the below class as an argument:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dialog-flow")
public class DialogFlowConfig {

    @NotNull
    public String projectId;

    @NotNull
    public String sessionId;

    @NotNull
    public String languageCode;
}
```

In theory, this should be instantiated by the below bean:

```
@Bean
public DialogFlowService dialogFlowService() {
   return new DialogFlowService(new DialogFlowConfig());
}
```

However in practice, when I try to log one of the constructor arguments, it comes up as null.  Am I missing something?

Comment: have you print this object `dialogFlowConfig` under `DialogFlowService`

Comment: You need to autowire `DialogFlowConfig` in the parameters for `DialogFlowService` bean. You also need to add `@Setter` (as you are using lombok), or manually add setters for the fields in `DialogFlowConfig`. Probably best to add getters as well and set the fields to private.

Comment: Do u mean that dialogFlowConfig.languageCode gives null?

Comment: Where is that `@Bean`? Also, it is not usually a good idea to mix `@Configuration` and `@ConfigurationProperties` on the same class; `@ConfigurationProperties` should be a simple record class.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- what makes you say that, official spring packages use `@Configuration` and `@ConfigurationProperties` in the same class

Comment: @123 It is _extremely_ easy to accidentally end up with multiple copies of the `@ConfigurationProperties` bean, which leads to errors with applying the values and with bean resolution.

Answer (score 2):

I think changing your third code snippet like this would do the trick.

```
@Bean
public DialogFlowService dialogFlowService(DialogFlowConfig  dialogFlowConfig) {
    return new DialogFlowService(dialogFlowConfig);
}
```

The `DialogFlowConfig` class is already marked as `@Configuration`. Hence it is managed by the Spring Application context. So you dont have to explicitly make an object using the new keyword. You can just take it as a parameter

Try putting `@EnableConfigurationProperties(DialogFlowConfig.class)` into you Spring Application class.

Comment: Still won't work, since the config class has no setters.

Comment: are you sure @123 that he needs setters? Because he has used the @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dialog-flow") in order to get those from any properties file there in his project right?

Comment: They still need to be set though.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. OP should wire up the bean and add getters/setters to the @ConfigurationProperties class.

Comment: @123 No you dont have to set any setters when using this way. If you have any answer kindly post it.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to what's being described here: [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Essentially, by instantiating the `DialogFlowConfig` instance yourself and not handing it over to Spring, you're preventing Spring from post processing it and injecting `ConfigurationProperties` property values.

Instead create a `@Bean` method for `DialogFlowConfig` and use the corresponding Spring bean to create your `DialogFlowService`. For example

```
@Bean
public DialogFlowService dialogFlowService(DialogFlowConfig dialogFlowConfig) {
    return new DialogFlowService(dialogFlowConfig);
}

@Bean
public DialogFlowConfig dialogFlowConfig() {
    return new DialogFlowConfig();
}
```

Spring will use the `@Bean` annotated `dialogFlowConfig()` factory bean method to instantiate and process the corresponding instance (setting its fields). It'll then use it with the `dialogFlowService()` factory method.

**Note:** If you do it this way, you'll need to remove `@Configuration` annotation from `DialogFlowConfig`, assuming you were previously component scanning it. Alternatively, if you were correctly component scanning, you don't even need the additional `@Bean` annotated `dialogFlowConfig()` factory method I proposed. Just inject the `DialogFlowConfig` bean declared by its `@Configuration` annotation in the `dialogFlowService` method.

Comment: @123 I missed the `@Configuration`, but it won't break. One bean will overwrite the other, since they have the same implicit bean name. Still, I left a note to clarify things.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to use either setter getter in DialogFlowConfig or @Value annotation on all properties. You also need to annotate your service class DialogFlowService with @Service stereotype